# Ursina box collider doesn't recognize intersection with raycast

Tags: python, collision-detection, collision, ursina

I have set a raycast that goes between 2 points. When they go through "N" boxes (called "scintillators" in the code) between those 2 points, the hit_info only returns 1 (hit) point - 3D Vec instead of "N" 3D hit points.

I tried to cycle through the boxes the raycast hit. When I activate box.intersects(), the hit_info that is returned has no detected collisions in it. That means that box collider doesn't recognize a raycast as intersection, and I can't tell what were the 3D points the raycast intersected each of the "N" boxes.

In the following picture you can see the hit_info of the raycast. This time it hit 5 boxes, but only 1 hit point is provided:

[image]

And now when I cycle through the boxes, and activate box.intersects(), the hit_info returned is empty:

[image]